# Identify plant with long narrow paired leaves and reddish stems

Tags: identification

Is this a chilli plant or am I nurturing weeds. I planted chillies last year but thought they died. Then I find this..

[image]

Comment: You also seem to be nurturing moss, which might indicate a more general problem with your growing conditions than a dead chilli.

Answer (score 9):

Well, it sure looks healthy and happy - but I’m afraid that is not a chili plant. If I had to do an id, I’d say a willowherb ([*Epilobium sp.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epilobium)). While also used for medicinal purposes, most gardeners will probably classify them as weeds<sup>1</sup>, especially as they are so resilient and happy to pioneer any unoccupied space, even if it’s just a spare flower pot.

---

<sup>1</sup> Gardener’s definition of weed: “Plant growing in a spot where it’s not wanted”.